# PHP - 404 Video Not Found (Videos: PUT) YouTube API

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube, youtube-api

I'm creating a small web app allowing people to update their video outside of YouTube. I'm currently testing for myself and i'm running into the

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "youtube.video", "reason": "videoNotFound", "message": "The video that you are trying to update cannot be found. Check the value of the \u003ccode\u003eid\u003c/code\u003e field in the request body to ensure that it is correct.", "locationType": "other", "location": "body.id" } ], "code": 404, "message": "The video that you are trying to update cannot be found. Check the value of the \u003ccode\u003eid\u003c/code\u003e field in the request body to ensure that it is correct." } }
```

Things that I know for certain:

- I have the correct authorization code
- I have the correct channel this authorization code refers to.
- I have the correct video id.

I'm sending a `PUT` request using cURL in PHP as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init($url . "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&access_token=".$token)

$data = array(
'kind' => 'youtube#video',
'id' => 'theCorrectIdIsHere',
'snippet' => array(
    "title" => "Test title done through php",
    "categoryId" => "1"
),
);`
```

So how come when I execute this using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: 
application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`
```

A similar question has been asked: [Update title and description using YouTube v3 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897966/update-title-and-description-using-youtube-v3-api), however, the answer involved him downloading and replacing the video which costs extra quota and simply **shouldn't have to be done**

**Note** Everything works fine on the API test done here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` to set the request data & using `Authorization` header to set access token :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

$data = array(
'kind' => 'youtube#video',
'id' => 'YOUR_VIDEO_ID',
'snippet' => array(
    "title" => "Test title done through php",
    "categoryId" => "1"
)
);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Amazing! Do you have an idea why it wasn't working for me?