# YouTube Livestream Update Script

Tags: bash, api, curl, youtube, youtube-api

I've been searching here and across the web for a bash script that leverages the YouTube API to update the Title, Description, Playlist, Category and Thumbnail given a YouTube livestream video ID.  My preference is to do this using bash/curl to keep it simple, but I've been unable to make any progress.

I've seen this question asked a few times, but the feedback given over the last couple years has been a redirect to the YouTube API documentation which I've gone through thoroughly, but have been unsuccessful in achieving the outcome described above.

Looking forward to any help you can provide.

Comment: At the risk of sounding redundant --  If you view that [Youtube API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets) --  Look on the right side of the page **Try this API**..  You can build out your query and hit  **SHOW CODE**  --  It will give you a perfectly usable `CURL` statement usable in `bash`

Comment: It will end up looking something like: `curl --insecure -v -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:  Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_GOOGLE_HERE" -d '{"id":"YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE","kind":"youtube#video","snippet":{"title":"My title","description":"My description","categoryId":"22"}}' "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet"` which can be seen answered in [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897966/update-title-and-description-using-youtube-v3-api/24900867)  If you're looking for a snippet pre-written in `bash` I am afraid you're out of luck.